# Multitenant Rails app - Strategies for pulling customer data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, jruby, multi-tenant

I am developing a multitenant Rails app using Postgresql schemas. All is going great, but my situation is a little different from the conventional multitenant apps out there; namely my app will require that I pull customer data for each tenant from their database to mine.

Here is where it gets tricky. I wrote a jRuby gem that connects to each customer's database and pulls data to my server, and then it processes that data and loads it into my Rails app (each customer set of data will end up in the appropriate tenant schema). Therefore this gem is the only place that it aware of all my tenants and their configuration (database info, which tables to pull, and so on).

My question is: What do you think of this design choice? Some of the problems I am already seeing is that this forced the app to be in two Ruby states, i.e. it normally functions in Ruby, but when I need to do a pull, I have to switch to jRuby. Furthermore, it is hard to inspect into tenant configuration without resort to this gem.

Any comments or feedback on this? Is there another path I could have taken with this?

Comment: Write a Ruby gem instead of a jRuby gem? Have the *Ruby* gem write configuration data to a database table that only *you* have SELECT privileges for?

Comment: jRuby is the only option given that the client is using a proprietary JDBC driver.

Comment: Furthermore I have no privileges on the customer data, except reading the tables assigned to me.